# Android listview doesn't expand all

Tags: android, listview

This is my design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:divider="#88888888"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My problem is the listview can't expand all items, I want to see all the items in the listview.

Comment: `ListView` is already a `A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list`. Why are you nesting it inside a `ScrollView` ?

Comment: That's my short design, actually I have more control above or below the list view so whenever I rotate my screen, some of them will be hidden, you know what I meant? I also have set the minHeight to the list view, but not affect anything

Comment: you are not suppose to put listview inside scrollview. if you needed put some view above listview, try looking at listview.addheaderview and listview.addfooterview. you can inflate some dynamic view add above of listview and it will scroll along with listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this inside your Java code

```
mListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside
        // ScrollView
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
            // child view
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```